# Built-in function for flatten a 3d array into pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a numpy array like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 4, 3))
```

I want to be able to flatten this data into a df with 12 columns and 1000 rows.

What I've done is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( index=range(data.shape[0]))

for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    for j in range(data.shape[2]):
        df[str(i)+'_'+str(j)] = pd.DataFrame((data[:,i,j]))
```

By doing so, I'll be able to flatten this 3d data into 2d pandas df.

**-** Does anyone know any neat built-in function that I can use, in addition to what I've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reshape the array to `(-1, 12)` and create the dataframe

```
 pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1, 12))
```